# Git tracks _lines_ of code. Is there something that track _words_?

Tags: version-control, git

In git if I change a character in a line the entire line is considered changed.

I don't know much but stackexchange seem to track changes in a word-by-word basis in the edit history.
Is there an option to make git like that, or is there anything else that does this?

Comment: resource requests generally don't fare well on Programmers.SE.  It would help your question if you explained _why_ you think it's important to track down to that level of detail.

Comment: @GlenH7 I was just intrigued. No actual purpose.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I wouldn't say it's inherently true that git tracks lines, not words. Git stores snapshots of the entire source tree. It just happens to display differences between those trees as a line-based diff. But that's only the default way of displaying things. You can do `git diff --word-diff` to see a word-based diff which may be more useful in some cases. Do `git help diff` to see a zillion other flags you can pass to `git diff`.

Comment: [Related answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/255202/how-do-i-view-git-diff-output-with-a-visual-diff-program) on setting up `git` to use an external `diff` utility—if you're on a Linux system you probably have `tkdiff` installed which does a nice color-coded word-by-word diff of each line side by side.